# $z^{19}=(-1+i)$ find the value of $z$. complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

I have to find the value of $z$ which satifsfies this equation and which has the second smallest positive argument $\theta$, $0<\theta<2\pi$. I have to find $r$ and $\theta$.
The answer I got was $r=2^{1/38}$ and $\theta$ of $11\pi/76$. However, the answer is incorrect.
Please help.

Comment: What are your toughts so far?. I really advice you to add more information if you don't want your question to get closed.

Comment: Have you heard of [De Moivre's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula)?  In particular, [how to take the root of a complex number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre's_formula#Roots_of_complex_numbers)?

Comment: Here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for displaying functions

Comment: @user230329 and @ AlexM. it is entirely possible that user230329 and user4995978 are the same person where the op had not remembered to log in before posting the question.  If so, it is confusing.

Comment: JMoravitz - I'm not the same user as the OP. 
AlexM - If i'm not mistaken, I've only formatted the mathematical symbols. If I changed something substantial - please edit\undo my edit.

Comment: @AlexM., if you look at the [edit history](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1625572/revisions), it does seem that user230329 added a sentence.  But if you look at the [source for the original post](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/12dbbcd6-b2ba-48b5-a8fe-90e9498636d6/view-source), the "added sentence" is there; the incorrect formatting hides it.

Answer (score 1):

We use DeMoivre's Theorem to find the $19$th roots of $-1 + i.$ We write this complex number in trigonometric form: $-1 + i = \sqrt{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right)\right).$ Notice that $r = \sqrt{2},$ $n = 19,$ and $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4}.$

Using DeMoivre's Theorem, we find our solutions to be the following:
$$\sqrt[19]{\sqrt{2}}\left(\cos\left(\frac{\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi k}{19}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{\frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi k}{19}\right)\right),$$
where $k = 0, 1, 2, ... , n - 1.$

Since you are seeking the solution with the second smallest positive argument $\theta,$ then $k = 1$ and $\theta = \frac{3\pi}{4} + 2\pi = \frac{11\pi}{4}.$ The answer is
$$\boxed{\sqrt[38]{2}\left(\cos\left(\frac{11\pi}{76}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{76}\right)\right)}.$$